# BigQuery - How to configure write disposition for a insert_rows job?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, jupyter, google-client

I'm creating a flow to insert rows in a BigQuery table from a list of dictionaries with the following format:

```
[
{'column1': 'value11', 'column2': 'value21', 'column3': [{'subfield1':'value131'}]},
{'column1': 'value12', 'column2': 'value22', 'column3': [{'subfield1':'value231'}]},
{'column1': 'value12', 'column2': 'value22', 'column3': [{'subfield1':'value331'}]}
]
```

I'm testing yet and wish to write truncate the table, but I don't know how to set the job_config for an insert_rows method. I set up a LoadJobConfig object as follows, but the insert_rows method doesn't accept job_config as a parameter.

```py
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=schema,
    write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
)
```

I'm not loading the from a DataFrame or a file because my table has nested fields and I didn't find out how to load nested data in those formats.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass `JobConfig` with `WRITE_TRUNCATE` mode. You have to execute a separated query to `truncate` the table, then append all your dicts to `BigQuery` with `insert_rows_json` :

```
your_dicts = [
   {'column1': 'value11', 'column2': 'value21', 'column3': [{'subfield1':'value131'}]},
   {'column1': 'value12', 'column2': 'value22', 'column3': [{'subfield1':'value231'}]},
   {'column1': 'value12', 'column2': 'value22', 'column3': [{'subfield1':'value331'}]}
]

# Truncate the table
bq_client = bigquery.Client()
query_job = bq_client.query(f"TRUNCATE table {table_id}")

results = query_job.result()

# Append your list of Dict to BQ
job = bq_client.insert_rows_json(table_id, your_dicts)
```

The `insert_rows_json` uses the following [insertAll api](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll).

Comment: Actually, I can pass JobConfig with WRITE_TRUNCATE to other methods but not with insert_rows_json. I ended up using load_table_from_json with the parameter job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(schema=schema, write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)

Comment: I undestand but I think my solution was good for the initial question. can you mark it as solved please ?

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand mazlum's answer, here it says you can use write_truncate https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).